# iPad / iPhone Offline Webpage

Tags: ipad, html, caching, offline

I need to supply a single page website for a client to view offline on an iPad / iPhone.

The webpage will have Javascript, image and video assets. Reading about Cache Manifest it seems the cache on iPad is limited to 5mb.

Anyone suggest any routes forward, which ideally do not require the use of an additional app, but will allow for the offline storage of video.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have trouble with Safari to guarantee availability of your web page and videos offline.

The most reliable alternative would be to create an app using [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com), because that would give you control over the video and the web page being stored offline. However that requires you to distribute it as an iOS-app to your client.

If you don't/can't distribute it as an app, you could try to find an app that is designed for offline browsing and supports video on the appstore. If you search for "Offline browser iPhone" on google or appstore you will be presented with some alternatives.